# How to get the area of the pixels of a raster in Africa Lambert Conformal Conic CRS in R

Tags: raster, r, area, pixel

My question has been previously asked here ([R How to multiply the values of the raster pixels with the true surfaces of these pixels?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247533/r-how-to-multiply-the-values-of-the-raster-pixels-with-the-true-surfaces-of-thes)), I have to multiply the precipitation value of each cell by the area corresponding to each of these pixels under R. **Except that** I am working with the EPSG: 102024, Africa-Lambert-Conformal-Conic Coordinate system. Is it then an unprojected raster? In ther words, do I also have to use the function raster(r)? If not, how can I get the area corresponding to each of these pixels of my raster in R?

Comment: I cant find that EPSG code on the epsg-registry web site - can you post the output of `summary` on your raster so we can see the projection string and the other parameters?

Comment: Okay I guess you mean ESRI 102024 - http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/102024/ - a proprietary code rather than EPSG.

Comment: If your data is in a raster with that projection string correctly set then the linked question applies - calling `area(r)` will return a raster with values equal to the area of your pixels.